# Why getchar is reading one more value?

Tags: c, getchar

I have the following code from The C Programming Language, that return the number of characters typed

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count characters in input; 1st version */
main() {
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

However, when I execute my program (charcounter.exe) in the command prompt in Windows, and enter a sequence of characters, the program prints one more. Just like in the following example

```
C:\...\c-folder>charcounter
abc
^Z
4
```

Why is this happening? I suppose maybe is because the ENTER I press, but when I try to type the entire sequence, then Ctrl + Z, and then ENTER, the program doesn't read the EOF character and keeps waiting for another.

```
C:\Users\juani\Desktop\c-folder>charcounter
abc^Z
^Z
4
```

Comment: Try `"abc"` ^z ^z. (no enter)

Comment: Or redirect stdin from a file. (or use a real OS ...)

Comment: Why is the `^Z` down and to the left?  Did you maybe type something?

Comment: That's how the Windows console works, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing it up a little bit `Ctrl-Z` only behaves as `EOF` when it's at the beginning of a line, if it's elsewhere all the characters in that line from `^Z` onwards will be ignored, that includes the `\n`, so for instance, for an input of `abcd`<kbd>ctrl-z</kbd>`asd`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, only 4 characters are counted in that line.

The rest is what you said, `\n` is also a character, so it gets counted, you can always exclude it from being counted with a condition if that is an option:

```
int main()
{
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c != '\n')
            ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```